# Creating chloropleth maps in geopands with 'user_defined' bins

Tags: python, geopandas, plotting

As suggested in the geopandas mapping tools [documentation](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mapping.html), I want to create a chloropleth map using a custom defined bin sizes:

```
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap='OrRd', scheme='user_defined')
```

Indeed, 'user_defined' is mentioned explicitely in the geopandas [plotting.py code on github.](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py)

However, when I attempt this, python (v 3.5, geopandas v 0.4.0) throws an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid scheme. Scheme must be in the set: dict_keys(['quantiles', 'equal_interval', 'fisher_jenks'])
```

Indeed, when inspecting the source code in my environment, the schemes are restricted to just these four.

How can it be that my Geopandas installation is not in sync with what's being suggested in the Geopandas docs and source code? According to Conda, I really have the latest version of Geopandas installed.

ANSWER:

I've cloned the Geopandas repo from Github. Using the plotting functionality from there, the following works:

```
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap='OrRd', scheme='user_defined', classification_kwds={'bins':[1000, 10000, 100000]})
```

Comment: Im trying with: `ud = pysal.esda.mapclassify.User_Defined(y=world.gpd_per_cap, bins=[200,250,300])`, and then pass ud as scheme but i get another error. See pysal doc [here](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/esda/mapclassify.html#pysal.esda.mapclassify.User_Defined). Have you seen this question and solution on SO: [Plotting a choropleth map (with geopandas) using a user_defined classification scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783090/plotting-a-choropleth-map-with-geopandas-using-a-user-defined-classification-s)

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? I have read the Q&A you are referring to. I don't think it should be necesary to mess with the Geoapandas source code as the top answer suggested. The Geopandas man pages suggest that 'user_defined' is already implemented.

Comment: I cant check now. But it was something like: un or User_Defined has no attribute lower / or start /etc. Try it yourself, just import pysal, adjust bins and use `scheme=un` in the plot line

Comment: I'll try that once back in the office. I think you're on the right track by first defining 'ud' as a Pysal object and then providing that to the plot function.

Comment: I think it isn't necessary to provide the scheme as a pysal object after all. The scheme argument is the 'user_defined' string. The Pysal binning object is generated in the __mapclassifiy_choro(values, scheme, **classification_kwds) function in plotting.py.

Comment: Please write your answer as an answer, rather than inside the body of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've cloned the Geopandas repo from Github. Using the plotting functionality from there, the following works:

```
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap='OrRd', scheme='user_defined', classification_kwds={'bins':[1000, 10000, 100000]})
```

Comment: As of 10/30/2019 this no longer seems to work. Can you confirm?

Comment: I just made this work, with the simple change of 'user_defined' to 'userdefined' -- it looks as though the official removal of the version with underscore was after @user128912 's post, but... like I said, works for me.